# cannot resolve symbol 'Animations' when i use this library from github https://github.com/smarteist/android-image-slider

Tags: java, android, android-activity, carousel, androidimageslider

i want to make image slider to my project, than i use this library https://github.com/smarteist/android-image-slider.

But when i copy and paste the code in my `MainActivity` the Animations inside `(SliderLayout.Animations.FILL)` is red?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SliderLayout sliderLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sliderLayout = findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
    sliderLayout.setIndicatorAnimation(SliderLayout.Animations.FILL); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.Animations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
    sliderLayout.setScrollTimeInSec(1); //set scroll delay in seconds :
    setSliderViews();

}
private void setSliderViews() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        SliderView sliderView = new SliderView(this);

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                sliderView.setImageUrl("https://images.pexels.com/photos/547114/pexels-photo-547114.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
                break;
            case 1:
                sliderView.setImageUrl("https://images.pexels.com/photos/218983/pexels-photo-218983.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
                break;
            case 2:
                sliderView.setImageUrl("https://images.pexels.com/photos/747964/pexels-photo-747964.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260");
                break;
            case 3:
                sliderView.setImageUrl("https://images.pexels.com/photos/929778/pexels-photo-929778.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
                break;
        }

        sliderView.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        sliderView.setDescription("setDescription " + (i + 1));
        final int finalI = i;
        sliderView.setOnSliderClickListener(new SliderView.OnSliderClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSliderClick(SliderView sliderView) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is slider " + (finalI + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //at last add this view in your layout :
        sliderLayout.addSliderView(sliderView);
    }
}
```

Comment: did u add these 
 implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.2.0'
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1' dependencies to your gradel file correctly ?

Comment: show your import statement also

Comment: yes, the  implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.2.0' implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1' is work properly in my gradle

Comment: here the full code: https://pastebin.com/j0tZRaHB

Answer (score 1):

As from this this library . you can see that .  There is a `com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderAnimations` class which is imported .

```
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderAnimations;
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout;
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.DefaultSliderView;
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView;
```

But in your case . Only this two .

```
 import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout;
import com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView;
```

so import animation class from your library.

Comment: Thank you bro +1, but its not the only problem, but i already found the answer. Thank You so much

Comment: @FahrulSanjayaC if it solved your problem then accept the answer . so it can help other also

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sliderLayout.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.FILL)
```